# Linq query on a Date giving an error "Nullable object must have a value."

Tags: entity-framework, linq

I have a list of objects that I'm passing into a function where I want to filter out records for a specific company and if a DateTime field is today.

I'm getting an error "Nullable object must have a value." when I do and I believe it is due to the fact that some of the "Verified_Date" fields are null, but not all of them.

This is the LINQ I came up with. Is there a way that I can filter out on a specific company and if there Verified_Date = today even if some of the records have a Verified_Date = NULL?

```
var today = DateTime.Today;
var listFiltered = data.Where(d => d.CompanyCode == companyCode && d.VerifiedDate.Value.Date == today).ToList();
```

Comment: but you want to include those records that have null?

Comment: Not in this list. I only want records that have been verified today. I have another function that I use to pull out those that haven't been verified in the last 10 days and send reminder emails from there.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
var today = DateTime.Today;
var listFiltered = data.Where(d => d.CompanyCode == companyCode 
                                && d.VerifiedDate!=null
                                && d.VerifiedDate.Value.Date == today).ToList();
```

Comment: Looks like that works! I'm going to do more testing but that looks good. Thanks for the help!

Comment: You're welcome. Nullable also has a property called `HasValue`, you should be able to use too instead checking if its not null.

Comment: Any performance issue with using != null vs HasValue or is one way better than the other?

Comment: No, it's the same

Answer (score 1):

Check that `VerifiedDate` isn't null in your `Where` condition.

```
var listFiltered = data.Where(d => d.CompanyCode == companyCode
                                && d.VerifiedDate != null
                                && d.VerifiedDate.Value.Date == DateTime.Today)
                       .ToList();
```